# Converting should expression to soft assertions

Tags: cypress, chai

I have a complex form with many individual features to test, and I'd like to traverse the whole page without failing the test. I've seen soft assertions but cannot figure out how to make it work with attributes such as `disabled`.

For example

```js
<input data-id="name"></input>
<input data-id="email"></input>
<input data-id="password" disabled></input>

cy.get('[data-id="name"]').should('not.be.disabled') 
cy.get('[data-id="email"]').should('be.disabled')            // fails - convert to soft assertion?
cy.get('[data-id="password"]').should('have.attr', 'disabled')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [alfonso-presa/soft-assert](https://github.com/alfonso-presa/soft-assert) to change the way `expect` works.

It would mean you have to alter the style of `.should()` to the callback version.

Also, since the `expect()` not longer fails when the expression is false, you lose retry capability. Only use this on a stable HTML page.

```js
const { proxy, flush } = require("@alfonso-presa/soft-assert");
expect = proxy(expect);

it('tests by soft assert', () => {

  cy.get('[data-id="name"]').should($el => expect($el).not.to.be.disabled) 

  // shows failed in log but test continues
  cy.get('[data-id="email"]').should($el => expect($el).to.be.disabled)  

  cy.get('[data-id="password"]').should($el => expect($el).to.have.attr('disabled')) 

  cy.then(flush)  // flush any errors
})
```

**Note**
The `flush()` method should be added to Cypress command chain, otherwise the test ends before it is evaluated.